# How to do carousel animation in Android?

Tags: java, android, carousel

I have some images, i want it to rotate like circularly in a Carousel  fashion. please let me know how to do it in android platform if anybody knows...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) with couple of ImageViews inside.

Answer (score 1):

This code will rotate a view 360 degrees:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(360,0);
rotateAnimation.setDuration(ROTATE_TIME);
myView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

To make it repeat:

anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

If you want the movement to have an even speed through the entire animation, check out this question that I asked a few month ago:

[Make ScaleAnimation move evenly, or figure out how it moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519856/make-scaleanimation-move-evenly-or-figure-out-how-it-moves)